# catch block not returning null value

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I am developing a flutter application for android . I am trying to authenticate the users via email.

```
Future signInwithEmailAndPassword({String email,String pass}) async {
    try{
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass);
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user);
    }catch(e){
      print('error occured');
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

here's the method I use to authenticate user with email and password.
the problem is **catch block is executed and the error message is printed in console, but it does not return a null value when I handle the returned value**

```
dynamic result = _authService.signInwithEmailAndPassword(email: email,pass: pass);
                      print(result);
                      if(result==null)
                        {
                          setState(() {
                            print('inside setstate');
                          });
                        }
```

When i receive the return value in the "dynamic result" variable and print it, it is showing the type as Future . I want the catch block to return the null value.
How to solve this?

Comment: try this : dynamic result = await _authService.signInwithEmailAndPassword(email: email,pass: pass);

Comment: @gladiator thanks dude, That was a silly mistake done by me , I forgot to add that , Anyways thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening bcz, it is not awaiting for the result, we have to wait until we get the result back. So , we need to put an await keyword in front of it. like this

```
dynamic result = await _authService.signInwithEmailAndPassword(email: email,pass: pass);
```